# Citrix Reciever (v. 4.9) won't install on Windows 10

Tags: windows, citrix

I can't get the Citrix Reciever install to complete on Windows, and always end up with the installation failing (I uninstall Citrix under apps and functions after trying to install Citrix). I have tried multiple versions of Citrix Reciever (4.9, 4.8, 4.7 and 4.6),

I have no previous versions of Citrix Reciever installed, and it's installing on a completely new computer.

A part of the view log says "Information - CApp::InitInstance(482) - SecureBoot is Unsupported in the system". This, however, is not true according to the systeminfo, that states that SecureBoot is turned on.

Does anyone have any fixes or tips?

Answer (score -1):

https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX137494

CLeanup tool might help,i have used it in the past

Comment: requires username and password.